# Infinite Loop until application gets signal

Tags: c++, c, multithreading

I have an application which starts 5 threads.

After starting those threads nothing happens in main().

```
main(){
      `start thread 1..5
}
```

How do I loop infinitely in main() so my program will run continuously until it gets a signal.

I don't want to use

```
while(true)
```

because it will eat CPU cycle. (As I think )

Edit:
I am using gcc 4 
Thread Api :pthread 
OS : Linux

Comment: Thread.Start()  :) Depends what you are using, BOOST, Win Threads, QT Threads?

Comment: What API/library do you use for threading? Where does the signal come from you are waiting for? Does you `main` do anything useful in the meantime, or does it only wait?

Comment: When you say "signal," do you mean an actual POSIX signal (SIGUSR1, etc.) or "until `main()` somehow knows it's safe to exit?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the simplest would be:

```
while (true) sleep(1000);
```

and the best would be to **join()** all the five threads.

Comment: will it not send whole application in sleep state ?

Answer (score 3):

The `sigsuspend()` function is designed for precisely this purpose - it will suspend the calling thread until it recieves a signal that results in the calling of a signal handler.

To avoid a race condition (where the signal arrives just before your process calls `sigsuspend()`), you should block the signal, check for it, then pass a mask to `sigsuspend()` that unblocks it:

```
/* Block SIGUSR1 */
sigset_t sigusr1set, origset;
sigemptyset(&sigusr1set);
sigaddset(&sigusr1set, SIGUSR1);
sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sigusr1set, &origset);

/* Set up threads etc here */

/* Unblock SIGUSR1 and wait */
sigdelset(&origset, SIGUSR1);
sigsuspend(&origset);
```

Comment: Nice answer!  Solved my problem.  I was halfway through posting a question about it too.  I was looking for an idiom to wait forever for signals, and pull dangerous work out of the handlers themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Join those threads see [pthread_join](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_join.html).

Comment: I can't join because , I am creating thread inside a object. and that variable is not visible.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [Boost::Synchronization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html) functions, like this:

```
main(){
  `start thread 1..5
  wait for signal
  exit
}
```

Comment: how to wait for signal in C++ linux ?

Comment: Boost is available for linux so you can use the synchronization methods boost gives you. As a bonus, it should work in Win32 without any changes.

Answer (score 1):

Windows?  Use [WaitForMultipleObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).